# Materializecss: imagem sem margin

Tags: css, materialize

Estou com uma imagem dentro de uma `div`. Em baixo ela fica com uma `margin`. Tentei com Firebug olhar o código da `div` e `img`, mas não encontrei nada declarado com `margin` e `padding`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s4">
        <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8380.jpg" alt=""/>             
    </div>
    <div class="col s4">
        <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8265.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4">
        <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8711.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Amigo a classe `row` do Materialize por padrão tem um margin-bottom de 20px , para resolver isso basta criar uma classe com o nome `.no-margin` e deixar ela com `margin: 0 !important;`, assim sempre que quiser uma div `row` sem margem basta adicionar assim:
HTML:

```
<div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col s4">
        <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8380.jpg" alt=""/>             
    </div>
    <div class="col s4">
        <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8265.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4">
        <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8711.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.no-margin {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou @Bruno Romualdo ainda esta aparecendo a margin. Vc tem alguma ideia pq?

Comment: Tem como colocar o codigo em algum JSFiddle fica mais facil ver e arrumar o problema.

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais simples de resolver isso, caso você ainda não tenha tentado, é ir na sua própria folha de estilo e definir um margin=0 pra figura. 
Pelo que me parece, o margin pode estar vindo tanto da classe "responsive-img" quanto da classe "row" ou da "col s4", então vale a pena tentar retirar o margin manualmente de cada uma delas.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o problema não seja nas imagens, e sim nas `div`s.

Crie uma classe `.no-margin` no seu `<style>` e adicione ela a `div` mãe. Nas `div`s filhas você adiciona a classe `.no-padding` nativa do Materialize:

```
<style>
.no-margin{
   margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col s4 no-padding">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8380.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4 no-padding">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8265.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4 no-padding">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8711.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```