# Espaçamento entre linhas

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, materialize

Estou usando o Framework Materialize em um site, porém quando crio duas linhas ele me da esse espaçamento, alguém sabe como corrigir?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s6 red">6</div>
  <div class="col s6 green">6</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s6 blue">6</div>
  <div class="col s6 yellow">6</div>
 </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Materializecss: imagem sem margin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245990/materializecss-imagem-sem-margin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa subscrever a class `.row` com valor `0` e acrescente o atributo `!important`, para que o mesmo possa subscrever o valor default.

Para subscrever as classes você precisa criar um novo arquivo css, e chamar ele depois do `Materialize`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/meu.css">
```

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 red">6</div>
    <div class="col s6 green">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 blue">6</div>
    <div class="col s6 yellow">6</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```